# get values from {id:3,name:"John"} from list.js

Tags: javascript, html, object, listjs

I made a list with listjs (listjs.com)

Now i'm using the function get(), this wil give me this return:

```
itemsInList = [
    { id: 1, name: "Jonny" }
    , { id: 2, name "Gustaf" }
];
listObj.get("id", 2); -> return { id: 2, name: "Gustaf" }
```

Now i'm want to get the name id with pure javascript only.

```
function getUserName(uid) {
    var itemValues = hackerList.get("id", uid)[0];
    console.log("The name of the user is: " + itemValues.name);
    // or use alert..
    //alert("The name of the user is: " + itemValues.name);
}
```

Sorry not concrete... I want from the return value:

**{ uid: 2, name: "Marc" ... }**

to **itemValues.name -> Marc**

**Udate**

Forgot to use uid function ("id"). When I use values() it will work. Thank you for the answer.

Updated Fiddle
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zoutepopcorn/HKfLf/)

Comment: What is the problem you want help with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your id field is called uid, and to get to the values of the object, you need to call .values on the result, so:

```
function getUserName(uid) {
    var itemValues = hackerList.get("uid", uid)[0].values();
    console.log("The name of the user is: " + itemValues.name);
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but isnt it a function from jquery? 
I get: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'values' of undefine

Comment: have you changed the hackerList.get("id", uid) to hackerList.get("uid", uid) ? In your fiddle example you named the id field "uid"

Answer (score 2):

You can use the arrays filter method (IE9+):

```
// Pure javascript list
var hackerList = [
    { uid: 1, name: 'John' },
    { uid: 2, name: 'Marc' }
];

function getUserName(uid) {
    var hackers = hackerList.filter(function(hacker) {
        return hacker.uid === uid;
    });

    if(hackers.length > 0) {
        console.log("The name of the user is: " + hackers[0].name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Its a way. But it will search the list again and I want to use listjs, also better for all browsers. Thank you.

Comment: I misunderstood you question, thought you didn't want to you list.js for some reason...